# Showing that $a_{n+1}=\frac{n}{a_n}-a_n-a_{n-1}$ with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1=2\Gamma(\frac34)\big/\Gamma(\frac14)$ stays positive for $n\geq1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

This posting consists of several mildly-related questions, motivated from [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2525989/9340). The main object is the following sequence.

$$a_0 = 0, \qquad a_1 = x, \qquad a_{n+1} = \frac{n}{a_n} - a_n - a_{n-1}. \tag{*}$$

**Question 1.** Numerical experiment suggests that there is a unique value of $x$ for which $a_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. Can we prove/disprove this?

If we write $I_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a_1 > 0, \cdots, a_n > 0\}$, then obviously $I_n$ is a nested sequence of open sets that begins with $I_1 = (0, \infty)$. Moreover, the experiment suggests that $I_n$ are all intervals, and the endpoints of $I_n$ are adjacent poles of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+1}$ is strictly monotone on $I_n$. Provided this is correct, we easily see that there is a unique zero of $a_{n+1}$ on $I_{n+1}$, which then determines $I_{n+1}$.

[image: Plots of a_{n+1} on I_n]

**Question 2.** The same experiment also suggests that the value of such unique $x$ is

$$ \frac{\operatorname{AGM}(1,\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}
= \frac{2\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}
\approx 0.675978240067284728995\cdots.$$

At this point, I completely have no idea why this value arises, but I have checked that this is correct up to hundreds of digits. (I progressively refined the range of $x$ so that $a_n$ stays positive for a longer time.) Again, will it ever have a chance to be proved?

My original suspicion was that we may rearrange the recurrence relation to obtain continued fraction, but it was of no avail. To be honest, I have never seen this type of problem, and will be glad if I can learn anything new about it.

**Question 3.** Given that the above question seems to bold to answer, perhaps we may consider its variants:

1. *(Variant 1)* $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = x$, and $a_{n+1} = \frac{n}{a_n} - a_n - p a_{n-1}$, where $p \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. *(Variant 2)* $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = x$, and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{a_n} - a_n - a_{n-1}$.
3. *(Variant 3)* $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = x$, and $a_{n+1} = \frac{n^2}{a_n} - a_n - a_{n-1}$.

Again, in each case, numerical experiment suggests that there is a unique $x$ for which $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ stays positive. Moreover,

- For Variant 1, it seems that $x = 1/\sqrt{3}$ for $p = -2$ but I have no guess for general $p$, even when it is an integer.
- For Variant 2, it is conjectured that $x = 4/3\sqrt{3}$.
- For Variant 3, we can check that $x = 1/\sqrt{3}$ is such one. Indeed, we find that $a_n = n/\sqrt{3}$ solves the recurrence relation.

Then we may ask whether the version of Question 1-2 can be proved for these variants.

---

**Progress.**

1. I managed to answer **Question 1**. Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3254721/9340).

Comment: This. Is. Hard.

Comment: Another variant is $a_0=w$, $a_1=x$, $a_{n+1} = n/a_n - a_n - a_{n-1}$. (So the original problem is $w=0$.) Numerical experimentation suggests that there is a curve of values $(w,x)$ for which the recurrence stays positive, and this curve slants gently down from roughly $(0, 0.7)$ to roughly $(1,0.4)$.

Comment: Continuing the experiments, if $x_n$ is the unique zero of $a_{n+1}$ on $\color{red}{I_n}$ (typo?), and $x=2\Gamma(3/4)/\Gamma(1/4)$ is the (conjectured) limit, then computations suggest $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x}{x-x_{n+1}}=2+\sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: I have just completed my answer to cover question 3, variant 1. There always is a unique $x$ leading to positive $a_n$, $n\geq1$. The proof is complicated for positive $p$, in particular in the range $1\leq p\leq 5$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer For nonnegative $w$ and $p$, the existence of a unique $x=x(w)$ such that the recursion $a_{n+1}=n/a_n-a_n-pa_{n-1}$ yields a positive sequence can be shown in the same way as in part 3, $p\geq0$ of my solution. I have not verified it, but I believe the same to be true for negative $w$ or $p$. By the way, the uniqueness of $x=x(w)$ implies, I think, the continuity of $x(w)$...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first part, I answer Question 2: I prove that the recursion 
$$\label{rec}\tag{1}a_{n+1}=\frac n{a_n}-a_n-a_{n-1}$$
yields a positive sequence for the initial values $a_0=0$, 
$a_1=2\Gamma(\frac34)/\Gamma(\frac14)$.

(\ref{rec}) is actually a special discrete Painlevé 1 equation. One survey article mentioned
[this article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077491237) by 
J. Shohat about orthogonal polynomials in which the recursion
first appeared. (See also 
[this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512358v1) which I found after completing my proof).
The following proof is inspired by Shohat's article. It also contains proofs
of some well known facts about orthogonal polynomials to be self-contained.

*Proof:* Consider the inner product $(p,q)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac14x^4}p(x)q(x)\,dx$
on the real vector space of all polynomials. Since the subspaces of all polynomials
of degree $\leq n$ have dimension $n+1$, there is, for $n\geq1$, a unique polynomial
$P_n(x)=x^n+...$ such that $(P_n,q)=0$ for all polynomials of degree $<n$. For convenience,
we put $P_0(x)=1$.
Since $e^{-\frac14 x^4}$ is even, we have $P_n(x)=(-1)^nP_n(-x)$ for all $n$: $P_n$ is even
or odd if $n$ is even or odd, respectively. Parity will be used in the sequel without 
mentioning it.

Claim 1: There are positive constants $\lambda_n$ such that
$$\label{eqa}\tag{2}P_{n+1}(x)-x\,P_n(x)+\lambda_n P_{n-1}(x)=0\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$

Proof: $P_{n+1}(x)-x\,P_n(x)$ has degree $<n$ and it is orthogonal to all polynomials $q$
of degree $<n-1$, because $(xP_n,q)=(P_n,xq)=0$. Hence there is a constant $\lambda_n$ such that
$P_{n+1}(x)-x\,P_n(x)=-\lambda_nP_{n-1}(x)$. This constant is positive because
$$\lambda_n(P_{n-1},P_{n-1})=(\lambda_nP_{n-1},P_{n-1})=(xP_n,P_{n-1})=(P_n,xP_{n-1})=(P_n,P_n)$$
and hence 
$$\label{eqlam}\tag{3}\lambda_n=(P_n,P_n)/(P_{n-1},P_{n-1})\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$

We also introduce, for $n\geq2$, the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in $P_n$ and name it $d_n$.
The relation (\ref{eqa}) implies by induction that
$$d_n=-(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}).$$
Now we can write, for $n\geq0$, 
$$\label{eqb}\tag{4}x^3P_n(x)=P_{n+3}(x)+h_nP_{n+1}(x)+\mbox{ terms of degree below } n.$$
Comparing the coefficients of $x^{n+1}$ shows that the constant 
$h_0=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ whereas $h_1=-d_4=\lambda_1+\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}$ and
$$h_n=d_n-d_{n+3}=\lambda_n+\lambda_{n+1}+\lambda_{n+2}\mbox{ for }n\geq2.$$

Now we multiply both sides of (\ref{eqb}) by $P_{n+1}$ and obtain
$(x^3P_n,P_{n+1})=h_n(P_{n+1},P_{n+1})$  for $n\geq0$. At this point, we use the special
form of our weight $e^{-\frac14 x^4}$ - so far, we just used that it is even.
We calculate
$$(x^3P_n,P_{n+1})=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{-\frac14 x^4}x^3\right)
   P_n(x)P_{n+1}(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac14 x^4}(P_nP_{n+1})'(x)\,dx $$
and hence $(x^3P_n,P_{n+1})=(P_n',P_{n+1})+(P_n,P_{n+1}')=(n+1)(P_n,P_n)$.
This yields together with (\ref{eqlam})
$$n+1=(\lambda_n+\lambda_{n+1}+\lambda_{n+2})\lambda_{n+1}\mbox{ for }n\geq1,$$
whereas $1=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda_1$. If
we put $\lambda_0=0$ for convenience, we have 
$$n=(\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda_n+\lambda_{n+1})\lambda_n\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
Together with $\lambda_0=0$, we have a sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n\geq1}$ of positive numbers
as asked in the OP. Now by (\ref{eqlam}) finally $\lambda_1=(x,x)/(1,1)=2\Gamma(\frac34)/
\Gamma(\frac14)$ because
$(1,1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac14 x^4}\,dx=2^{-1/2}\Gamma(\frac14)$ and
$(x,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac14 x^4}x^2\,dx=2^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac34)$.
This completes the proof.

In part 2, we prove that for the recursion from Question 3, Variant 2, there exists a unique value $x>0$
such that the sequence determined by the initial condition $a_0=0$, $a_1=x$ remains positive for
all positive $n$ and that the value of this $x$ is $\frac4{3\sqrt3}$.

It is more convenient
to work with the sequences $(b_n)$ determined by $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt3}b_n$. They satisfy the recursion
$$\label{rec2}\tag{5} 3=(b_{n+1}+b_n+b_{n-1})b_n\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$

Uniqueness: Any positive sequence $(b_n)$ satisfying (\ref{rec2})  obviously satisfies
$b_n\leq\sqrt3$ for all $n$. Using the recursion in the form $b_n=3/(b_{n+1}+b_n+b_{n-1})$
now yields that $b_n\geq1/\sqrt3$ for $n\geq 1$. Now $b_n^2+b_{n+1}b_n\leq3$ for $n\geq1$
yields that $b_n\leq B$ for $n\geq1$, where $B$ is the positive solution of 
$B^2+3^{-1/2}B=3$. In particular $B<\sqrt3$.

Suppose now that $(b_n)$ and $(b_n')$ are two positive sequences satisfying (\ref{rec2}).
Then, as seen above $1/\sqrt3\leq b_n,b_n'\leq B<3$ for $n\geq1$. Now put $d_n=b_n'-b_n$ for
$n\geq0$. Then $d_0=0$. We assume that $d_1\neq0$. The sequence $(d_n)$ satisfies
a recursion obtained by taking the difference of those for $(b_n)$ and $(b_n')$. It is
$$\label{recd}\tag{6}d_{n+1}=-\left(\frac3{b_nb_n'}+1\right)d_n-d_{n-1}.$$
Hence we have recursive inequalities
$$|d_{n+1}|\geq\left(\frac3{b_nb_n'}+1\right)|d_n|-|d_{n-1}|\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
These allow to prove by induction that
$$|d_{n+1}|\geq \frac3{b_nb_n'}|d_n|\geq|d_n|\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
Again by induction, it follows that $|d_n|\geq \left(\frac3{B^2}\right)^{n-1}|d_1|$
for all $n\geq1.$ Since $B^2<3$, this contradicts the fact that all $|d_n|\leq B-3^{-1/2}$.
Hence the assumption $d_1\neq0$ was false and there is at most one positive sequence
satisfying (\ref{rec2}).

Existence, first proof: Here we consider every element $b_n=b_n(x)$
of the sequence satisfying (\ref{rec2}) as a (rational) function of the initial value $b_1(x)=x$.
We show

*Claim 2:* There exist a sequence $(I_n)_{n\geq1}$ of nested compact intervals 
(that is $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$) such that
a) $b_k(I_n)\subset[3^{-1/2},3^{1/2}]$ for $1\leq k\leq n$.
b) $b_n(I_n)=[3^{-1/2},3^{1/2}]$ for all $n\geq1$.
Since the intersection $\bigcap_{n\geq1}I_n$ of nested compact intervals is nonempty, it contains some
$x$ such that $b_n(x)>0$ for all $n\geq1$. Thus Claim 2 implies the existence of 
such an $x$.

*Proof of Claim 2:* By induction. For $n=1$, we simply choose $I_1=[3^{-1/2},3^{1/2}]$. Suppose now that we have found
$I_1,\dots,I_N$ such that a), b) hold for $1\leq k\leq n\leq N$. Then there exist $t, T\in I_N$ such that
$b_N(t)=3^{-1/2}$, $b_N(T)=3^{1/2}$ and $b_{N-1}(t)\leq 3^{1/2}$, $b_{N-1}(T)\geq 3^{-1/2}$.
This leads to $b_{N+1}(t)=3/b_N(t)-b_N(t)-b_{N-1}(t)\geq 3^{3/2}-3^{-1/2}-3^{1/2}>3^{1/2}$ and
$b_{N+1}(T)=3/b_N(T)-b_N(T)-b_{N-1}(T)=-b_{N-1}(T)<0$. We assume $t<T$; in the opposite case the
considerations are analogous. Now we apply the intermediate value theorem: 
We choose $s\in[t,T]$ maximal such that $b_{N+1}(s)=3^{1/2}$. Then $b_{N+1}(\tau)<3^{1/2}$ for $s<\tau\leq T$.
Now we can choose $S\in [s,T]$ minimal with $b_{N+1}(S)=3^{-1/2}$. Then $S>s$ and 
$3^{-1/2}<b_{N+1}(\tau)<3^{1/2}$ for $s<\tau<S$. If we put $I_{N+1}=[s,S]\subset I_N$ then
a), b) hold for $1\leq k\leq n\leq N+1$. This completes the proof of Claim 2.

Existence, second proof. Here we show that $b_n$, $n\geq1$ are positive if $b_1=4/3$. This proves the conjecture
for Variant 2. The recursion (\ref{rec2}) shows that all $b_n$ are rational, we find for the first $b_n$.
$$b_2=\frac{11}{12}, b_3=\frac{45}{44}, b_4=\frac{164}{165}, b_5=\frac{616}{615}.$$
This suggests

*Claim 3:* $b_n=1+1/d_n$, where $d_{n+1}=-4d_n-d_{n-1}-1$ for $n\geq1$ and $d_0=-1$, $d_1=3$.

This Claim implies, of course, that all $b_n$, $n\geq1$ are positive.

Proof of Claim 3: We consider the sequence $d_n$, $n\geq0$ of integers recursively defined as above.
We first show
$$\label{rel}\tag{7}d_{n-1}d_{n+1}=d_n+d_n^2\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
To show (\ref{rel}), we proceed by induction. For $n=1$, it is true. If it is true
for some $n$, we calculate
$$\begin{array}{rcl} d_nd_{n+2}-d_{n+1}-d_{n+1}^2&=&d_n(-4d_{n+1}-d_n-1)-d_{n+1}-d_{n+1}^2\\
         &=& d_{n+1}(-4d_n-d_{n+1}-1)-d_n-d_n^2=d_{n+1}d_{n-1}-d_n-d_n^2=0.
\end{array} $$

Now we *put* $b_n=1+\frac1{d_n}$. If we want to prove that they satisfy (\ref{rec2}), we actually have to show that
$$\frac1{d_{n+1}}=-\frac3{d_n+1}-\frac1{d_n}-\frac1{d_{n-1}}\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$

To show this, we calculate using (\ref{rel}) and the recursion for the $d_n$
$\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}$
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\ds-\frac3{d_n+1}-\frac1{d_n}-\frac1{d_{n-1}}&=&
    \ds\frac{-4d_nd_{n-1}-d_{n-1}-d_n-d_n^2}{d_n(d_n+1)d_{n-1}}\\
   &=&\ds\frac{d_{n-1}(d_{n+1}+d_{n-1})-d_{n-1}d_{n+1}}{d_{n+1}d_{n-1}^2}
 =\ds\frac1{d_{n+1}}.\end{array}$$
This completes the proof.

In part 3, I consider Variant 1 and prove that, for any real $p$, there 
exists a unique value $x>0$ such that the recursion
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}\tag{8}a_{n+1}=\frac n{a_n}-a_n-p\,a_{n-1}
\mbox{ for }n\geq1\end{equation}
yields a positive sequence for the initial values $a_0=0$, 
$a_1=x$ and that $x=1/\sqrt{3}$ for $p=-2$.

Existence: We will use repeatedly that for any real $z$ and positive integer $n$, the equation
$\frac ny-y=z$ has exacty one positive solution. It can be given explicitly as
$y=-\frac z2+ \sqrt{\frac{z^2}4+n}$.

We first prove
Lemma 1: There exist two sequences $L_n,U_n$, $n\geq0$ such that $L_0=U_0=0$, $0<L_n<U_n$
for all $n\geq1$ and
$$\frac n {U_n}-U_n-p t\leq0\mbox{ for all }n\geq1\mbox{ and }t\in[L_{n-1},U_{n-1}],$$
$$\frac n {L_n}-L_n-p t\geq U_{n+1}\mbox{ for all }n\geq1\mbox{ and }t\in[L_{n-1},U_{n-1}].$$
Proof: We have to distinguish the cases: $p\geq0$ and $p<0$.
In the case $p\geq0$, we choose $U_n=\sqrt{n}$ for all $n$. Then the first inegualities is
satisfied whatever $L_n$ we choose. The second inequalities are satisfied
if we choose as $L_n$ the unique positive solution of
$\frac n{L_n}-L_n=U_{n+1}+p\,U_{n-1}$.
In the case $p<0$, we choose recursively $U_n$ as the unique positive solution of
$\frac n{U_n}-U_n=p\,U_{n-1}$. Again, the first inequalities are satisfied whatever we choose for
$L_n$. The second inequalities are now satisfied if we choose recursively
$L_n$ as the unique positive solution of $\frac n{L_n}-L_n=U_{n+1}+p\,L_{n-1}$.

Here again, we consider every element $a_n=a_n(x)$
of the sequence satisfying (\ref{eq3}) as a (rational) function of the initial value $a_1(x)=x$.
Using Lemma 1, we can now show in a way identical to Claim 2:

*Claim 4:* There exist a sequence $(I_n)_{n\geq1}$ of nested compact intervals such that
a) $a_k(I_n)\subset[L_k,U_k]$ for $1\leq k\leq n$.
b) $a_n(I_n)=[L_n,U_n]$ for all $n\geq1$.
Since the intersection $\bigcap_{n\geq1}I_n$ of nested compact intervals is nonempty,
it contains some
$x$ such that $a_n(x)>0$ for all $n\geq1$. Thus Claim 4 implies the existence of 
such $x$.

Observe that in the case $p=-2$, we can simply choose $a_n=n/\sqrt{3}$ and recursion (\ref{eq3})
is satisfied.

Uniqueness: In the case $q=-p>0$, use $a_{n+1}a_n+a_n^2=n+q\,a_na_{n-1}$ in two ways.
First we estimate
$$a_n^2\leq n+qa_na_{n-a}\leq n+\frac12a_n^2+\frac{q^2}2a_{n-1}^2,$$
hence
\begin{equation}\label{est1}\tag{9}a_n^2\leq 2n+ q^2 a_{n-1}^2.\end{equation}
Then, we estimate using (\ref{est1})
$$n\leq a_n^2+a_na_{n+1}\leq2a_n^2+\frac14a_{n+1}^2\leq \left(2+\frac{q^2}4\right)a_n^2+\frac {n+1}2$$
and find that there is a constant $c$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{unt1}\tag{10}a_n\geq c\sqrt{n}\mbox{ for }n\geq1.\end{equation}

Now we distinguish 3 subcases:
If $q>2$ then the equation $t^2+t=q$ has exactly one positive solution $t=\mu>1$.
The negative solution is $t=-\mu-1$. Therefore, we rewrite the inequality following from 
(\ref{unt1}): 
$a_{n+1}+a_n-qa_{n-1}=\frac n{a_n}\leq \frac1c\sqrt n$ 
as
$$(a_{n+1}+(\mu+1)a_n)-\mu(a_n+(\mu+1)a_{n-1})\leq\frac1c\sqrt n$$
and conclude that
$$a_{n}+(\mu+1)a_{n-1}\leq \mu^{n-1}a_1 +\frac1c\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mu^{n-1-j}\sqrt j\leq C \mu^n,$$
where $C=\frac1\mu a_1+\frac1{c\mu}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sqrt j\mu^{-j}$.

If $q=2$ then we obtain $\mu=1$ and in the same way that 
$a_n+2a_{n-1}\leq C n^{3/2}$ with some constant $C$.
If $0<q<2$ then the equation $t^2+t=q$ has exactly one positive solution $t=\mu<1$ and 
the negative solution is again $t=-\mu-1$. We conclude as above that there is a constant $C$
such that $a_n+(\mu+1)a_{n-1}\leq C \sqrt{n}$.

Altogether, we found that for all $q$ and every solution of (\ref{eq3}) there is a constant $C$
such that $a_n\leq C n^{3/2}\max(1,\mu)^n$, where $\mu$ is the positive solution of $t^2+t=q$.

Now if $a_n$, $a_n'$, $n\geq0$ are two positive solutions of (\ref{eq3}) then the sequence
$d_n=a_n-a_n'$ satisfies $d_0=0$ and
$$d_{n+1}=-\left(\frac{n}{a_na_n'}+1\right)d_n+qd_{n-1}\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
Since $q>0$, the sequence $d_n$ is alternating and we have
$$|d_{n+1}|=\left(\frac{n}{a_na_n'}+1\right)|d_n|+q|d_{n-1}|\geq2|d_n|+q|d_{n-1}|
 \mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$

Using the unique solution $\lambda>2$ of $t^2=2t+q$, 
we rewrite this as 
$$|d_{n+1}|+(\lambda-2)|d_n|\geq \lambda\, (|d_{n}|+(\lambda-2)|d_{n-1}|)\mbox{ for }n\geq1.$$
This implies by induction that $|d_{n}|+(\lambda-2)|d_{n-1}|\geq \lambda^{n-1}|d_1|$ and hence
also $|d_n|\geq\lambda^{n-1}|d_1|/(\lambda-1)$.
Now the previous considerations show that there is a constant $C$ such that
$|d_n|=|a_n-a_n'|\leq C n^{3/2}\max(1,\mu)^n$ where $\mu$ is the positive solution of $t^2+t=q$.
Since $\max(1,\mu)<\lambda$, the assumption $|d_1|>0$ would lead to a contradiction.
Thus $d_1=0$, hence all $d_n=0$ and $a_n=a_n'$ for all $n$.
This proves uniqueness in the case $q=-p>0$.

The proof of the uniqueness of $x$ in the case $p>0$ is very different.
We will use as an essential tool the function $w(n,z)$ defined for real $z$ and positive integer
$n$ as the unique positive solution $w$ of $\frac nw-w=z$. It can be given explicitly as
\begin{equation}\nonumber
w(n,z)=-\frac z2+\sqrt{\frac{z^2}4+n}=\frac n{\frac z2+\sqrt{\frac{z^2}4+n}}.
\end{equation}
Observe that for any positive $n$, the mapping $z\to w(n,z)$ is strictly decreasing
because the derivative of the mapping $w\to\frac nw-w$ is always negative.

Step 1:
Consider now a sequence $a_n$, $n=0,1,\dots$, verifying (\ref{eq3}) for some parameter $p\geq0$.
Note that we do not indicate the dependence upon $p$ of most objects below with the exception of
some ``constants'' in step 4.

We have
$a_{n+1}a_n+a_n^2+pa_{n-1}a_n=n$ for $n\geq1$. Hence
\begin{equation}
\label{ineqbas}\tag{11}a_n\leq\sqrt n\mbox{ and }a_{n-1}a_n\leq\frac np\mbox{ for }n\geq1.
\end{equation}
Using the sequence $U_1(n)=\sqrt{n}$, we have
$0\leq a_n\leq U_1(n)$ for all $n$.
Now define $L_1(n)$ by $L_1(0)=0$ and $L_1(n)=w(n,U_1(n+1)+pU_1(n-1))$ for $n\geq1$.
Since $a_{n+1}+pa_{n-1}\leq U_1(n+1)+pU_1(n-1)$, we find that
$a_n=w(n,a_{n+1}+pa_{n-1})\geq L_1(n)$ for all $n$. We have $0\leq L_1(n)\geq w(n,0)=U_1(n)$
for all $n$.

Next, define $U_2(0)=0$ and $U_2(n)=w(n,L_1(n+1)+pL_1(n-1))$ for positive $n$.
Then $0\leq L_1(m)\leq a_m\leq U_1(m)$
for $m=n-1,n+1$ imply that $L_1(n)\leq a_n \leq U_2(n)\leq U_1(n)$ for all $n$.
Continuing like this we define $L_2(0)=0$ and $L_2(n)=w(n,U_2(n+1)+pU_2(n-1))$ for positive $n$
and find
$L_1(n)\leq L_2(n)\leq a_n \leq U_2(n)$ for all $n$.

In the same way, we define the sequences $U_k(n)$, $L_k(n)$, $n=0,1,...$ satisfying
\begin{equation}\nonumber
U_{k+1}(n)=w(n,L_k(n+1)+pL_k(n-1))\mbox{ and } L_k(n)=w(n,U_k(n+1)+pU_k(n-1))
\end{equation}
and $L_k(n)\leq L_{k+1}(n)\leq a_n \leq U_{k+1}(n)\leq U_k(n)$ for all $n$ and every positive
sequence $a_n$ satisfying (\ref{eq3}).

Finally, we consider the pointwise limits
\begin{equation}\nonumber
U(n)=\lim_{k\to\infty}U_k(n)\mbox{ and } L(n)=\lim_{k\to\infty}L_k(n)
\end{equation}
which exist because for fixed $n$, the sequences $U_k(n)$, $L_k(n)$, $k=1,2,...$
are monotonous and bounded. The properties of the sequences $U_k$, $L_k$ imply
besides $U(0)=L(0)=0$
a) $L(n)\leq a_n\leq U(n)$ for every $n$ and every positive sequence $a_n$
satisfying (\ref{eq3}),
b) $U(n)=w(n,L(n+1)+pL(n-1))$ and $L(n)=w(n,U(n+1)+pU(n-1))$ for all positive $n$.
As a consequence of b), the two sequences $A_n,B_n$, $n=0,1,...$, defined by
$A_n=U(n),\,B_n=L(n)$ if $n$ is even and
$A_n=L(n),\,B_n=U(n)$ if $n$ is odd
both satisfy the recursion (\ref{eq3}).
The uniqueness of $x$ defining a positive sequence via recursion (\ref{eq3}) is proved once we
show
*Claim 5:* $L(n)=U(n)$ for all $n$ or, equivalently, $A_n=B_n$ for all $n$.

Observe that the above construction of $L(n)$ and $U(n)$ can be used to approximate
the unique positive sequence $a_n$ satisfying (\ref{eq3}).
For $p=1,3,10$, we find
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
p=1&0.6760&0.8034&1.010&1.156&1.294&1.416&1.529&1.634&1.733&1.827\\
\hline
p=3&0.7671&0.5365&0.8900&0.8713&1.050&1.099&1.210&1.277&1.360&1.427\\
\hline
p=10&0.9066&0.1964&0.9192&03804&0.9443&0.5470&0.9798&0.6947&1.023&0.8243
\end{array}
\end{equation}
This sequence $a_n$, $n=0,1,...$ is not monotonous for small $n$ unless $p$ is small.
This contributes to the difficulty of proving the uniqueness.

Step 2
In order to prove the Claim 5, i.e. uniqueness, consider the non-negative
sequence $D_n=(-1)^n(A_n-B_n)$. It satisfies $D_0=0$ and
\begin{equation}\label{eqD}\tag{12}
D_{n+1}=\left(\frac n{A_nB_n}+1\right)D_n-p\,D_{n-1}\mbox{ for }n\geq1.
\end{equation}
The subtraction makes the present case $p\geq0$ harder than the previous one $p<0$,
in particular for
large $p$. For small $p$, things are easy. It is sufficient to use
$$D_{n+1}\geq 2D_n-p\,D_{n-1}$$
which follows from (\ref{ineqbas}) and (\ref{eqD}).
If $0\leq p<1$, then using the solution $\lambda\in]1,2]$ of $\lambda=2-\frac p\lambda$,
we can show by induction that $D_{n+1}\geq\lambda D_n$ for all $n\geq1$.
Indeed, this inequality is true for $n=1$ and if we have $D_{n}\geq\lambda D_{n-1}$, then
$D_{n-1}\leq \frac1\lambda D_n$ and hence
$$D_{n+1}\geq 2D_n-p\,D_{n-1}\geq\left(2-\frac p\lambda\right)D_n=\lambda D_n.$$
As a consequence, we find for all $n\geq1$ that
$D_n\geq \lambda^{n-1} D_1$ which contradicts
$D_n=|A_n-B_n|\leq\sqrt n$ unless $D_1=0$ (yielding $A_n=B_n$ for all $n$).
If $p=1$, we prove similarly that $D_{n+1}\geq\frac{n+1}n D_n$ for all $n\geq1$ and
hence $D_n\geq nD_1$ again contradicting $D_n\leq\sqrt n$ unless $D_1=0$.
For $p>1$, we have to work considerably harder to prove uniqueness.

Step 3
We prove some auxiliary statements improving (\ref{ineqbas}). These are valid for any
positive sequence $a_n$ satisfying (\ref{eq3}).
\begin{equation}
\label{anbelow}\tag{13}
a_n\geq \frac1{r(p)}\sqrt n,\mbox{ for all }n\geq1\mbox{ and }p\geq1,
\mbox{ where }r(p)=1/w(1,p+1).
\end{equation}
Proof: We have
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\frac n{a_n}-a_n=a_{n+1}+pa_{n-1}\leq\sqrt{n+1}+p\sqrt{n-1}\leq (p+1)\sqrt n
\end{equation}
since $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n-1}\leq2\sqrt n$. Hence $b_n=a_n/\sqrt n$ satisfies
$\frac1{b_n}-b_n\leq p+1$ and hence $b_n\geq w(1,p+1)=1/r(p)$.
\begin{equation}
\label{anabove}\tag{14}
a_n\leq\frac1{q(p)}\frac n{\sqrt{n-1}}\mbox{ for all }n\geq2,\,p\geq1,\mbox{ where }
q(p)=1/w(1,(p+1)/r(p)).
\end{equation}
Proof: We have using (\ref{anbelow})
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\frac n{a_n}-a_n=a_{n+1}+pa_{n-1}\geq \frac1 {r(p)}(\sqrt{n+1}+p\sqrt{n-1})
   \geq\frac{p+1}{r(p)}\sqrt{n-1}.
\end{equation}
Thus $a_n\leq w(n,\frac{p+1}{r(p)}(n-1))\leq\frac n{\sqrt{n-1}}w(1,\frac{p+1}{r(p)}).$

Observe that $r(p)$ and $q(p)$ are increasing with $p$. Here we use that
$\frac{p+1}{r(p)}=1/\left[\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\frac 1{(p+1)^2}}\right]$.
\begin{equation}
\label{anan-1}\tag{15}
a_na_{n-1}\leq \frac n{t(n,p)}\mbox{ for all }n\geq3,p\geq1,\mbox{ where }
   t(n,p)=\frac p2+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4+\frac{n(n-2)}{(n-1)^2}q(1)^2}.
\end{equation}
Proof: We have $a_n^2+pa_{n-1}a_n\leq n$, hence
\begin{equation}\nonumber
a_n\leq -\frac p2 a_{n-1}+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4a_{n-1}^2+n}
    =\frac n{\frac p2 a_{n-1}+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4a_{n-1}^2+n}}.
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}\nonumber
a_na_{n-1}\leq \frac n{\frac p2+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4+\frac n {a_{n-1}^2}}}.
\end{equation}
The rest follows using (\ref{anabove}): $\frac n{a_{n-1}^2}\geq n q(p)^2\frac{n-2}{(n-1)^2}
\geq\frac{n(n-2)}{(n-1)^2}q(1)^2$.
Note that $q(1)\geq 1.4966$.

For $n=2$, the same proof shows using $a_1\leq1$ that
\begin{equation}\label{a2a1}\tag{16}
a_2a_1\leq \frac 2{t(2,p)}\mbox{ where }
        t(2,p)=\frac p2+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}4+2}.
\end{equation}
Observe that $t(n,p)$ increases with $p$ and also increases
with $n\geq3$.

Step 4 Assume that $p\geq1$ and that we do not have uniqueness. Then $A_n\neq B_n$
for all $n\geq1$. Otherwise, that is if $A_n=B_n$ for some $n\geq1$
then in the case $n=1$ we of course have $A_n=B_n$ for all $n$ by the recursion.
In the case $n>1$ we have by construction $pA_{n-1}+A_{n+1}=pB_{n-1}+B_{n+1}$
and hence $A_{n-1}=B_{n-1}$ and $A_{n+1}=B_{n+1}$ because the differences
$A_{n-1}-B_{n-1}$ and $A_{n+1}-B_{n+1}$ cannot have opposite sign by construction.
This leads to $A_n=B_n$ for all $n$ also in the second case.

The recursion (\ref{eqD}) indicates that $D_{n+1}/D_n$ might be large if $A_nB_n$ is small.
This suggests to introduce the sequence $F_n=A_nB_n\frac{D_{n+1}}{D_n}$, $n\geq1$,
where again $D_n=(-1)^n(A_n-B_n)$.
We show later
*Lemma 2:* We have $F_n\geq\frac12n$ for all $n\geq1$.
If the Lemma is proved, Claim 5 follows readily. Using the definition of $F_n$ and
(\ref{anabove}), we find that
$D_{n+1}/D_n\geq\frac{n-1}{2n}q(p)^2\geq\frac{n-1}{2n}q(1)^2\geq\frac{n-1}{2n}\cdot2.23$
and this is larger than $C:=1.0035$ if $n\geq10$. Therefore $D_n\geq C^{n-10}D_{10}$
for $n\geq 10$ contradicting $D_n=|A_n-B_n|\leq \sqrt n$. Thus the assumption $A\neq B$
must have been false and Claim 5 is proved.

Proof of Lemma 2: First by (\ref{eqD}), we have
$F_1=A_1B_1D_2/D_1=A_1B_1+1$.
We estimate $A_1$ using $\frac1{A_1}-A_1=A_2\leq\sqrt2$ and obtain
$A_1\geq w(1,\sqrt2)$. We have as well $B_1\geq w(1,\sqrt2)$.
We conclude that
$F_1\geq1+w(1,\sqrt2)^2=:C_1\geq1.267$.

We have by (\ref{eqD})
\begin{equation}\label{eqF}\tag{17}
F_n=n+A_nB_n-\frac {pA_nB_nA_{n-1}B_{n-1}} {F_{n-1}}
\end{equation}

For $n=2$, we find
$$\begin{array}{crlcl}F_2&=&2+A_2B_2-\frac {pA_2B_2A_{1}B_{1}} {F_{1}}\\
  &\geq&  2+A_2B_2A_1B_1-\frac {pA_2B_2A_{1}B_{1}} {F_{1}}
   &\geq&
  2+pA_2B_2A_{1}B_{1}\left(\frac1p-\frac1{F_1}\right) .\end{array}$$
If $p\leq F_1$, then we find that $F_2\geq2$.
Otherwise, we use (\ref{a2a1}) and find
$$F_2\geq 2+\frac {4p}{t(2,p)^2}\left(\frac1p-\frac1{F_1}\right)\geq
   2+\frac {4}{t(2,p)^2}-\frac {4p}{t(2,p)^2C_1}.$$
In order to minimize the right hand side
it is convenient
to use $t=t(2,p)$ as independent variable and replace $p=t-\frac2t$.
Thus we have to minimize
$$g(t)=2+\frac4{t^2}-\frac4{C_1t}+\frac8{C_1t^3}.$$
This is a polynomial of degree 3 in the variable $s=1/t$
and can easily be minimized for positive $s$ using elementary calculus. Observe that
the derivative with respect to $s$ is negative for $s=0$ and strictly increasing.
Therefore there is a unique minimum on the set of all $s\geq0$.
We find that $F_2\geq C_2:=1.559$.

For $n=3$, we find in the same way
$F_3\geq  3+pA_3B_3A_{2}B_{2}\left(\frac1{2p}-\frac1{F_2}\right)$
and either $F_3\geq3$ in case $p\leq F_2/2$ or else using (\ref{anan-1})
$$F_3\geq 3+\frac{9}{2t(3,p)^2}-\frac{9p}{C_2t(3,p)^2}.$$
To minimize the right hand side, we use again $t=t(3,p)$ as independent variable
and replace (see (\ref{anan-1})) $p$ by $p=t-\frac34\frac{q(1)^2}{t}$. Thus we have to
minimize here
$$g(t)=3+\frac9{2t^2}-\frac9{C_2t}+\frac{27q(1)^2}{4C_2t^3}.$$
Here, we find
$F_3\geq C_3=1.931.$
Thus we have shown $F_n\geq\frac n2$ for $n=1,2,3.$

For $n\geq4$, we proceed analogously for the inductive step. So we assume that
$F_{n-1}\geq\frac12(n-1)$. First we use (\ref{eqF}), estimate using (\ref{anabove})
that $1\geq\frac{n-2}{(n-1)^2}q(p)^2A_{n-1}B_{n-1}$ and hence with $q(p)\geq q(1)$
$$F_n\geq n + A_nB_nA_{n-1}B_{n-1}\left(\frac{n-2}{(n-1)^2}q(1)^2-\frac p{F_{n-1}}\right).$$
If the big parenthesis is positive, we are done. Otherwise, we use (\ref{anan-1}) and the
induction hypothesis:
$$F_n\geq n + \frac{n^2}{t(n,p)^2}\left(\frac{n-2}{(n-1)^2}q(1)^2-\frac{2p}{{n-1}}\right).$$
We obtain $F_n\geq n/2$ if and only if
$$\frac12+\frac1{t(n,p)^2}\left(\frac{n(n-2)}{(n-1)^2}q(1)^2-\frac{2pn}{{n-1}}\right)\geq0$$
for all $n\geq 4$ and $p\geq1$.
Again, if the big parenthesis is positive, there is nothing to prove. If it is negative,
we can use that $t(n,p)$ increases with $n$ and then that the parenthesis becomes less negative
with $n$. Therefore it is sufficient to prove the inequality for $n=4$ and all $p\geq1$.
This can be done in the same way as before using $t=t(4,p)$ as independent variable
and $p=t-\frac{8q(1)^2}{9t}$. So we have to minimize here
$$g(t)=\frac12+\frac89 q(1^2)\frac1 t^2 - \frac8{3t}+\frac{64}{27}q(1)^2\frac1{t^3}$$
and check that the minimum is positive.
We find as minimum $g(1/0.3028416...)=0.02248044...>0$. This completes the proof of
the Lemma. Thus Claim 5 and hence uniqueness is proved also for $p>1$.

Comment: Very informative answer (and articles). Thanks a lot!

Comment: (+1) This is a truly enlightening solution, allowing me to taste a bit of a whole new area. Thank you so much for that!

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much for your appreciation and the many points! Actually, I first tried to express $a_n$ in terms of Gamma functions (in view of the asymptotic expansion which can be proved, but does not help for the value of $a_1$), but this does not work. Then I had the idea that it might be a discrete Painlevé equation. Right now I am working on Variant 1. Several cases have to be distingished...

Comment: Thank you again for this great contribution. The connection to discrete Painlevé equation is really an amusing and entertaining one to me, I really like it. I haven't checked part 2 yet but it is surprising that it can be solved in a rather elementary way. I will get my hands on part 2 when I get free time.